# How to make vim theme looks exactly as on screenshot

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

I've tried dozens of different themes but always get wrong coloring.

For example:

[This](https://github.com/danilo-augusto/vim-afterglow#latex) is how `vim-afterglow` should look with `LaTeX` code.

This is mine screenshot:

[image]

[This](https://github.com/danilo-augusto/vim-afterglow#python) is example for Python. And this is mine:

[image]

Colors are wrong for all themes I've tried: `afterglow`, `dracula`, `darcula`, etc.

I've tried different tweaks like setting `t_Co` to different values, setting `$TERM` to different values, combining previous tweaks.

I've tried different terminals: `gnome-terminal`, `tilda`, `xterm`, `tilix`, `st` and `xfce4-terminal`.

I use Ubuntu 16.04, nvim v0.3.4

**UPD:**

[This](https://github.com/dracula/vim) is how `dracula` should look like.

My screenshot:

[image]

Problems:

1) function name, `var` and `this` keywords are grey but should have different colors as on authors screen.

2) `function` keyword is green but should be cyan

3) Current line number is not highlighted

4) Line numbers color is blue but not grey

5) Other colors are not exactly as on screenshot

**UPD 2:**

I've used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/821163/167196) command to test 256 color support.

My output:

[image]

**UPD 3:***

Screenshot with `pangloss/vim-javascript` installed:

[image]

Comment: You probably need a terminal that supports 256 color. Make sure truecolor (`termguicolors`) is not interfering. I maintain dracula—what is not working?

Comment: At a second guess, the colors may be being dumbed down for term support as well as potentially highlighting syntax groups not recognized by your vim. I suggest speaking yo afterglow’s mainters

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I've added screen and described problems I have with `dracula`

Comment: from experience i can safely say that part of the problem is vim’s default js syntax *sucks*. I think i use pangloss/vim-javascript (or similar name) on github to fix that.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I've added new screenshot. Looks like some colors have been swaped

Comment: Hm. Its possible the screenshot is outdated. Please feel free to take up the dracula stuff in our github issues; i recommend going to each colorschemes issues page instead of here because youre more likely to get a better response

Comment: @D.BenKnoble ok, I will create new issue, thank you